# Syntax error passing query through neo4jclient

Tags: c#, neo4j, neo4jclient

I have some code that I got from [cypher examples](https://github.com/Readify/Neo4jClient/wiki/cypher-examples#create-a-user) which I modified to try and make it simpler to make it work.  The other reason I want to modify it is because I am trying to capture some sort of result to ensure the operation succeeded or failed, or ???.  So far I haven't been able to figure that out, so that is one question.  The other question is with the code below, I realize it's ugly but it's not working yet and I'll clean it when it's working.

```
var newUser = new {Id = model.Password.ToString(), Name = model.UserName.ToString() };

var mee = client.Cypher
                        .Create("(user:Name {newUser})")
                        .WithParam("newUser", newUser);

                    mee.ToString();
```

This failed to insert a record but didn't cause an exception in the try catch it is in.  The mee variable has the query, which I can see why it failed but can't figure out how to fix it.

```
mee = CREATE (user:Name { Id = 'aaaaaa', Name = 'ab' })
```

For the query, the equal (=) sign needs to be a colon (:).  With that, the query should work.  Second question, any way to achieve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you aren't calling `.ExecuteWithoutResults()` or `.Results`, so nothing will ever actually go to Neo4j.

Look at the full example that you linked to:

```
var newUser = new User { Id = 456, Name = "Jim" };
graphClient.Cypher
    .Create("(user:User {newUser})")
    .WithParam("newUser", newUser)
    .ExecuteWithoutResults();
```

If you want to return something, then you need to include that in your Cypher call with a `RETURN` clause, and then look at the `Results` property:

```
var newUser = new User { Id = 456, Name = "Jim" };
var createdUser = graphClient.Cypher
    .Create("(user:User {newUser})")
    .WithParam("newUser", newUser)
    .Return(user => user.As<User>)
    .Results
    .SingleOrDefault();
```

In this specific example though, that is totally pointless because you will always just return the same node you created.

As for the `=` vs `:`, that's just a difference of `QueryText` vs. `DebugQueryText`. Look at `QueryText`, because that's the one that actually goes over the wire in the end.

Comment: Removing .ExecuteWithoutResults was one of the modifications I made because if I left that in there I am not able to capture the results of the .Create.  Using .Results gives a different error I wasn't able to get past:  Error 1 'Neo4jClient.Cypher.ICypherFluentQuery' does not contain a definition for 'Results' and no extension method 'Results' accepting a first argument of type 'Neo4jClient.Cypher.ICypherFluentQuery' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Results is only available once you actually return something in your Cypher. I've updated my answer to include this scenario. Either way, you *have* to execute the query by calling either ExecuteWithoutResults, or Results. Without this, nothing will happen.